# Ubnutu 18.04 - Where can I find the menu bar from a desktop window that is in use?

Tags: 18.04, settings

The list of options used to be part of the window or at the top left of the screen in Ubuntu 16.04.
I know that Alt brings up the menu for the internet browser, but I'm not able to find any of the settings options for the desktop window on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You mean a Nautilus window options? You need some specific options?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 (starting from 17.10), which now uses Gnome Shell as desktop instead of Unity, the menu bar, if available, is presented in the document window. If it is not there, then the application has no menu bar.

There is indeed a trend in some applications to completely get rid of application menus. Most gnome applications, including the file manager (Files, aka nautilus), the document viewer (evince) do not have a menu bar. You will find the options through buttons in the main window and through the right-click menu. There is an "application" menu, that contains options applicable to the application as a whole. This menu is represented by the program name in the top bar. For many applications that do not care about that new trend, the application menu will only contain a "Quit" option.

So if you do not see a menu bar in the main window, then it is not there at all.